# Is there a way to get the Twitter user id/Twitter username from the real name of the person?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, twitter

I am working on ipad application. I want to search the twitter profile by using fullname or email id or contact number. Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`users/search`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/search) method of the Twitter REST API.

Comment: Searching using full name is working fine. But it is giving large number of users information. Is there any method to search based on email-id, so that we can get unique profile?

Comment: That is the only user search endpoint they offer, so no, not officially. I don't know of any unofficial ones either.

Answer (score 1):

try..

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/username.json
```

or

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/username.xml


NSString *userName = @"janusfidel"
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/%@.json".",userName];
```

create http request and use that as url.

Comment: No longer works since Twitter updated to api 1.1. Check out the changes here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview